# Unable to create SharePoint Farm via SQL Alias

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, configuration-wizard, sql-alias

I am trying to create SharePoint 2013 farm using SQL Alias. I did create SQL alias ahead of time and I was able to verify connectivity using a udl file and that is working without any issue. However, I have tried to create SharePoint farm (single server) using manual steps and also using AutoSPInstaller and I am getting the same error:

Cannot connect to database master at SQL server SP2013DEV. The database might not exit, or the current user does not have permissions to connect to it.

Also, we are getting event ID: 5586

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          10/23/2015 10:07:08 AM
Event ID:      5586
Task Category: Database
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          CNP\svc_farm
Computer:      ew.en.org
Description:
Unknown SQL Exception -1 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Note: SQL 2012 standard edition is installed on the same box
Firewall is disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: It may be a user permission issue, for further solutions, please check [Cannot connect to database master at SQL server in SharePoint](https://itcore.devoworx.net/cannot-connect-database-master-sql-server-sharepoint-configuration-wizard/) & [Cannot connect to database master at SQL server in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/01/29/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-servername-the-database-might-not-exist-or-the-current-user-does-not-have-permission-to-connect/)

Answer (score 1):

this kind of issue likely due to connectivity with database; possible firewall issue - firewall blocking communication. But as you mentioned Firewall disabled and everything on same server then i am guessing it is related to TCP IP and Names pipes. Make sure it is enabled, if not enable them then restart the server.

Check below blogs for more troubleshooting:

[SharePoint 2013: cannot connect to database at SQL server at... The database might not exist..](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24493.sharepoint-2013-cannot-connect-to-database-at-sql-server-at-the-database-might-not-exist.aspx)

[SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me mentioned in this blog: https://codecreature.wordpress.com/2014/08/11/create-and-configure-sql-server-instance-and-alias-for-sharepoint-installation/

Basically I added port 1433 as mentioned in step 4 of the above article
The below screen shot taken also from the above blog:

[image]